# Woocommerce's functions shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Let's say I want render some element of single product page of woocommerce, on any other page in wordpress exactly the same way. I would like just put a shortcode with a product ID on my page and for example product gallery will render. The problem is that I don't understand PHP in fact but I don't give up.

I figured out that it is possible create a custom function in the file functions.php located in my child theme...

```
function my_function() {
   return 'Hello!!';
}
```

...and then put my shortcode

```
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_function');
```

The question is How can I put into body of my function a method used by woocommerce? I guess, for this case it is following:

```
wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\product-image.php
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The `product-image.php` template relies on the global `$product` object so I think you can use define the global `$product` object yourself and then call `woocommerce_show_product_images()` in your shortcode, that's the template function that loads the `product-image.php` template.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce already has this `shortcode` available:

```
[product id="99"]
[product sku="FOO"]
```

Please refer to the documentation for more information https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Also, if you need this in a template, you can simply add:

```
echo do_shortcode('[product sku="FOO"]');
```